# Text Editor in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Would you mind help me this problem?

I used Visual Studio 2015 and my code automatically like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
  {}
```

But now I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and that is my code:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
{}
```

How can I make the format of VS2013 code like VS2015?

Sorry my English so bad.

Thank you for your help =)

Comment: You didn't say which language you are using. And why are you missing the curly braces for your first `for` statement?

Comment: That is not how VS2013 formats code.  Maybe you changed Tools > Options > Text Editor settings, maybe it doesn't know it is code, maybe you did not explain enough in your question.  Ask a colleague or friend to look over your shoulder and help you write a better question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I use C++ language.  In VS2015, I didn't use the curly braces for my first "for" statement but VS automatically made my code like that. In VS2013, It don't do that.